# How can i compare 2 different arrays and delete duplicated records that already exist in second array from first array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have two different arrays and I'm trying to avoid duplicates.

I tried looping through arr1 against looping through arr2 and when there is a match it should delete the value from arr1

```
def gmail_interviews 
  arr1 = []
  arr2 = []

  arr1 = [{"from"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>",
    "to"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "date"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "subject"=>[{"name"=>"From", "value"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>"}],
    "snippet"=>"interview booked"},
   {"from"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>",
    "to"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "date"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "subject"=>[{"name"=>"From", "value"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>"}],
    "snippet"=>"Interview booked for tomorrow"}]

  arr2 = [{"from"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>",
    "to"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "date"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "subject"=>[{"name"=>"From", "value"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>"}],
    "snippet"=>"interview booked"},
   {"from"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>",
    "to"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "date"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@gmail.com>",
    "subject"=>[{"name"=>"From", "value"=>"chinedu abalogu <chineduabalogu@yahoo.com>"}],
    "snippet"=>"Interview booked for tomorrow"}]

  arr1.each_with_index do |id, index|
    if !arr2.empty?
      arr2.each_with_index do |i, ind|
        if i == id
          puts "Cant save duplicated message to db\n #{id}"
          arr1.delete_at(index)
        end   
      end 
    end
  end

  render json: arr.as_json

end
```

from my code, it loops through arr1 once and twice for arr2 and stops instead of looping twice in both arrays as they both contain 2 values count

Basically it finds duplicate for arr1[0] and deletes after that it does not loop through arr1[1]

the return value should be nil or empty as both arrays have the same values.. please what am i missing?

Comment: What does the final output want to be, a single array with no duplicates? If so then `(arr1 + arr2).uniq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
arr1 - arr2
```

?

E.g.:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [2,3,10]
# => [2, 3, 10]
arr1 - arr2
# => [1, 4]
```

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-2D)